# Centering an auto-sized image both horizontally and vertically

Tags: html, css

I've done a lot of searching and found quite a few answers to this problem, but none of them seemed to work when I tried them in my particular setup. Here is a JSFiddle of the problem I am trying to solve:

http://jsfiddle.net/kr394ye2/1/

```css
.classA {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
}
.classB {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="classA">
    <img class="classB" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/ida-b-wells-153rd-birthday-4853060954226688-hp.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the image, which is automatically sized to the div it is contained in, to be centered both horizontally and vertically in the div. I cannot make the image the background of the div.

I have tried auto margins with various types of display (inline, inline-block). I've tried the text-align property, as well as vertical-align. I've tried the center tag. Nothing I tried has worked.

A solution should center the image both horizontally AND vertically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the inline block + pseudo element tricks.

```css
.classA {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 0;
}
.classA:after {
    content: "";
    height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.classB {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="classA">
    <img class="classB" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/ida-b-wells-153rd-birthday-4853060954226688-hp.jpg">
</div>
```

Note, the solution works only if the image is the only child inside the container, plus the container has a known height set.

By the way `<img>` is self-closing tag, `<img></img>` is wrong syntax, just use `<img src="">` or `<img src="" />`.

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS as bellow

```
.classB {
    Margin:auto;
    max-width: 50px;
    max-height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: This does not work. I tried in the JSFiddle provided above.

Comment: Add in CSS `position:relative `

Comment: That still doesn't work. You do realize you can test in the JSFiddle before posting, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you need vertical AND horizontal centering then this is what you need

http://jsfiddle.net/M_Elf/38kgyzwu/2/

in general

```
    margin:0 auto;
```

is making wonders

or else: if you only need horizontal centering just use

```
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

on your main wrapper

Answer (score 0):

Change your CSS to the following:

```
.classA {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 5px;
}

.classB {
    display: block; margin: auto;
    object-fit: cover;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

The CSS `object-fit: cover` helps to fit the image without losing quality.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kr394ye2/8/)

Read more about `object-fit` here: [object-fit - MDN Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit)

Comment: This changes the original code though. The idea is that the object should not be stretched, but rather should fit in the div respecting aspect ratio.

Answer (score 0):

You said you tried block and inline-block; did you try display table-cell for the containing div?  that generally will give you what to need to force the aligment you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go — you need four lines of code (not including css vendor prefixes):

- `text-align: center;` of parent element does the trick for horizontal positioning
- `position: relative;` `top: 50%;` `transform: translateY(-50%);` centers image vertically

I added two blocks with different sizes but same other properties for you to see that it's universal. Checked that in latest chrome, safari, IE10 and Opera, it works consistently.

```css
.classA {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 300px;
    height: 50px;
    float: left;
    
    text-align: center;
}

.classB {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 300px;
    max-height: 50px;
       
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.classA2 {
    background-color: yellow;
    width: 100px;
    height: 70px;
    float: left;
    
    text-align: center;
}

.classB2 {
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    max-width: 100px;
    max-height: 70px;
       
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(-50%);
        -ms-transform: translateY(-50%);
            transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.separator {
    display: block;
    clear:both;
    padding:20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="classA">
    <img class="classB" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/ida-b-wells-153rd-birthday-4853060954226688-hp.jpg"></img>
</div>
<div class="separator"></div>
<div class="classA2">
    <img class="classB2" src="https://www.google.com/logos/doodles/2015/ida-b-wells-153rd-birthday-4853060954226688-hp.jpg"></img>
</div>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I'm not sure why, but this code doesn't perfectly vertically center some images. Some are off by about a pixel or two. Still, it's very close and much cleaner than the other solutions.